# How to prevent python requests from percent encoding my URLs?

Tags: python, url, python-requests, percent-encoding

I'm trying to GET an URL of the following format using requests.get() in python:

[http://api.example.com/export/?format=json&key=site:dummy+type:example+group:wheel](http://api.example.com/export/?format=json&key=site%3adummy+type%3aexample+group%3awheel)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import requests

print(requests.__versiom__)
url = 'http://api.example.com/export/'
payload = {'format': 'json', 'key': 'site:dummy+type:example+group:wheel'}
r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
print(r.url)
```

However, the URL gets percent encoded and I don't get the expected response.

```
2.2.1
http://api.example.com/export/?key=site%3Adummy%2Btype%3Aexample%2Bgroup%3Awheel&format=json
```

This works if I pass the URL directly:

```
url = http://api.example.com/export/?format=json&key=site:dummy+type:example+group:wheel
r = requests.get(url)
```

Is there some way to pass the the parameters in their original form - without percent encoding?

Thanks!

Comment: It is a [standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). What is wrong with it?

Comment: @alecxe: The site I'm querying doesn't seem to work with percent encoded URLs and I get unexpected response.

Comment: I got this problem with Google Maps API and comma in `location=43.585278,39.720278` and I didn't find solution.

Comment: Ran into the same problem as the OP. A json api I am "forced" to use doesn't like the url passed to it to be encoded. Had to build a string. Didn't know about the safe=':+' option listed below.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

It is not good solution but you can use directly `string`:

```
r = requests.get(url, params='format=json&key=site:dummy+type:example+group:wheel')
```

---

**BTW:**

Code which convert `payload` to this string

```
payload = {
    'format': 'json', 
    'key': 'site:dummy+type:example+group:wheel'
}

payload_str = "&".join("%s=%s" % (k,v) for k,v in payload.items())
# 'format=json&key=site:dummy+type:example+group:wheel'

r = requests.get(url, params=payload_str)
```

---

**EDIT (2020):**

You can also use `urllib.parse.urlencode(...)` with parameter `safe=':+'` to create string without converting chars `:+` .

As I know `requests` also use `urllib.parse.urlencode(...)` for this but without `safe=`.

```
import requests
import urllib.parse

payload = {
    'format': 'json', 
    'key': 'site:dummy+type:example+group:wheel'
}

payload_str = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload, safe=':+')
# 'format=json&key=site:dummy+type:example+group:wheel'

url = 'https://httpbin.org/get'

r = requests.get(url, params=payload_str)

print(r.text)
```

I used page https://httpbin.org/get to test it.

Comment: Thanks, That's what I'm currently doing to make it work. I'm looking for a solution similar to the (obsolete) one described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scraperwiki/spEFwwzxrQA). Thanks anyway!

Comment: I was looking for better solution (similar to the obsolete one) in requests source code but I didn't find it.

Comment: worked for me. seemingly not great, but gets the job done. i thought there might be some easier solution by adjusting the encoding within the `requests` object.

Comment: I use "%XX" where XX are hex digits. Sending strings for params works until I try to send something larger than 2F, at which point I get an "Invalid control character" error

Comment: `urllib.parse.urlencode` is not ignoring curly braces during parsing. `self.response = requests.get(SteamQuery.queries[self.query_type], params=urllib.parse.urlencode(self.query_params,safe=":{}[]"))`
`input_json=%7Bappids_filter:[892970]%7D`

Comment: For me, setting a string as params causes an error due to the ```&``` symbols.
I need to use ```requests.get()``` with the base url, some parameters, and some (user, pw) argument to ```auth```. The result is ```Warning {"success":false,"code":400,"message":"Parameter ... of value ... violated a constraint... value, does not match requirements ([0-9]+,?)+```

Answer (score 15):

In case someone else comes across this in the future, you can subclass requests.Session, override the send method, and alter the raw url, to fix percent encodings and the like.
Corrections to the below are welcome.

```
import requests, urllib

class NoQuotedCommasSession(requests.Session):
    def send(self, *a, **kw):
        # a[0] is prepared request
        a[0].url = a[0].url.replace(urllib.parse.quote(","), ",")
        return requests.Session.send(self, *a, **kw)

s = NoQuotedCommasSession()
s.get("http://somesite.com/an,url,with,commas,that,won't,be,encoded.")
```

Comment: I know this wasn't in the OP's question but this doesn't work for the path portion of the URL (at the time of this comment).

Comment: In modern versions of requests, you actually also are gonna have to patch `urllib3`; it performs its own encoding. `requests.urllib3.util.url.PATH_CHARS.add(',')`. This starts to get into "more hacky than it's probably worth" territory, but if you _REALLY_ need it... here it is

Answer (score 15):

The answers above didn't work for me.

I was trying to do a get request where the parameter contained a pipe, but python requests would also percent encode the pipe. So 
instead i used urlopen:

```
# python3
from urllib.request import urlopen

base_url = 'http://www.example.com/search?'
query = 'date_range=2017-01-01|2017-03-01'
url = base_url + query

response = urlopen(url)
data = response.read()
# response data valid

print(response.url)
# output: 'http://www.example.com/search?date_range=2017-01-01|2017-03-01'
```

Answer (score 11):

The solution, as designed, is to pass the URL directly.

Comment: The idea behind using the payload dictionary to keep the actual code somewhat cleaner - as suggested [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls).

Comment: I found this old comment by @Darkstar kind of funny as the answer he's responding to is by the author of `requests`.

Comment: @DustinWyatt Wow! I don't know how I missed that!

Comment: This is the most straightforward and verified working solution. Ditch the payload dictionary and slap all those parameters right into the url.

Comment: No this will not work, `requests` of latest version will encode the characters even if you pass the URL directly.

Comment: @oeter: I don't find this to be true. See [toy example](https://imgur.com/a/sahmIWD).

Comment: @Hendy `print(requests.post("https://google.com?{}").url)` -> `https://google.com/?%7B%7D`

Answer (score 5):

All above solutions don't seem to work anymore from requests version 2.26 on. The suggested solution from the GitHub repo seems to be using a work around with a PreparedRequest.

The following worked for me. Make sure the URL is resolvable, so don't use 'this-is-not-a-domain.com'.

```
import requests

base_url = 'https://www.example.com/search'
query = '?format=json&key=site:dummy+type:example+group:wheel'

s = requests.Session()
req = requests.Request('GET', base_url)
p = req.prepare()
p.url += query
resp = s.send(p)
print(resp.request.url)
```

Source: https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/5964#issuecomment-949013046

Answer (score 3):

### Requests and Urllib3 don't allow raw URLs anymore!

- Since those libraries enforce RFC3986 url encoding implicitly.
- Previously available workarounds are now defunct:

  - Even the prepped request workaround doesn't work anymore!

=> To perform raw path requests another library must be used like "http".

### Raw Url Request Wrapper

- Wrapping the http library provides similar request methods but will not implicitly modify urls, thus allows to send urls as is
- Code:

```py
import http.client
from urllib.parse import urlparse

class HttpWrapper:

    def parse_url(self, url):
        p_url = urlparse(url)
        host = p_url.hostname
        port = p_url.port
        path = p_url.path
        assert host
        assert port
        
        return host, port, path

    def request(self, url, method, headers={}, data=None):
        # Parse url
        host, port, path = self.parse_url(url)

        # Perform request
        try:
            conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(host, port)
            conn.request(method, path, data, headers)
            response = conn.getresponse()
            return response
        finally:
            conn.close()
    
    def get(self, url, headers):
        return self.request(url, "GET", headers)

    def post(self, url, headers, data):
        return self.request(url, "POST", headers, data)

    def put(self, url, headers, data):
        return self.request(url, "PUT", headers, data)
    
    def delete(self, url, headers):
        return self.request(url, "DELETE", headers)
```

Comment: PSA: This seems quite incomplete and forces the user to always specify a port and headers, does not support HTTPS etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the 1st option in this [github link](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/1454#issuecomment-20832874). You can ignore the `urlib`part which means `prep.url = url` instead of `prep.url = url + qry`