# Disable urlencoding in python requests module

Tags: python, python-requests

Is there any way that we can disable the url encoding in python requests ?

What I want to do :
  I want to send at the data section a key pair value but I do not want the value to get url encoded .

Is there any switch ?

Thank you !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent python requests from percent encoding my URLs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23496750/how-to-prevent-python-requests-from-percent-encoding-my-urls)

Comment: I do not want json data