# Python Requests Messing with Links in my Data Dict

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I've got a request that looks like this:

```
data = {
    'USER': params['PARTNER'],
    'PWD': params['PWD'],
    'RETURNURL': 'https://my-site.com/',
    'CURRENCY': 'USD',
}

request = requests.post(url=URL, data=data, verify=False)
```

When I run this command in an identical cURL command in the shell, there's no problem at all. But when I do it through requests, it seems like something gets messed up with the RETURNURL parameter. It's preserved perfectly in cURL, but when processed from requests, it ends up looking like this when I see it on the other side of the request and things just don't work:

```
https%3A%2F%2Fmy-site.com%2F
```

Thanks in advance, been at this forever!

---

The actual command being used successfully in cURL is this:

```
curl https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com \
  -s \
  --insecure \
  -d PARTNER=PayPal \
  -d PWD=MyPassword \
  -d VENDOR=MyMerchantID \
  -d USER=MyMerchantID \
  -d TENDER=C \
  -d ACCT=5105105105105100 \
  -d TRXTYPE=S \
  -d EXPDATE=1221 \
  -d RETURNURL=https://my-site.com/
  -d AMT=1.00
```

Note that everything is working perfectly, but the parameter I submit which is a URL is the one that simply won't work and the formatting is all messsed up.

Comment: Show the curl command you are using. And what is processing the data on the other side? Is it an application you control?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm accessing a PayPal API, will update the post with some more info in 30 seconds

Comment: OK but how do you know how the URL is being received by PayPal?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Well the RETURNURL parameter is not necessary, so if I take it out everything works fine. But I need that parameter in there to customize the functionality for my use-case.

Comment: Similar to this question here - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23496750/how-to-prevent-python-requests-from-percent-encoding-my-urls

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're sending the data as JSON, then send the data with the `json` parameter instead of `data`

```
request = requests.post(url=URL, json=data, verify=False)
```

Comment: Added some more detail about the cURL command in the original post for reference.

Comment: I would double-check that; JSON string values don't get processed (which you can verify by calling `json.dumps` on your dictionary). I just run both cases locally, using Charles proxy to check the payload. The JSON payload is sent unmodified, the string payload is URL-encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Use `--trace-ascii log.txt` to log down curl post process.

curl

```
=> Send data, 161 bytes (0xa1)
0000: PARTNER=PayPal&PWD=MyPassword&VENDOR=MyMerchantID&USER=MyMerchan
0040: tID&TENDER=C&ACCT=5105105105105100&TRXTYPE=S&EXPDATE=1221&RETURN
0080: URL=https://my-site.com/&AMT=1.00
```

requests with `data = data_dict`

```
Content-Length: 169

ACCT=5105105105105100&TENDER=C&EXPDATE=1221&PARTNER=PayPal&RETURNURL=https%3A%2F%2Fmy-site.com%2F&VENDOR=MyMerchantID&USER=MyMerchantID&TRXTYPE=S&AMT=1.00&PWD=MyPassword
```

So you can try to post your data as string, as @Mortz said.

```
import requests

data = {
    'PARTNER':'PayPal',
    'VENDOR':'MyMerchantID',
    'TENDER':'C',
    'ACCT':'5105105105105100',
    'TRXTYPE':'S',
    'EXPDATE':'1221',
    'AMT':'1.00',
    'USER': 'MyMerchantID',
    'PWD': 'MyPassword',
    'RETURNURL': 'https://my-site.com/',
}
data = "&".join("{}={}".format(k,v)  for k,v in data.items())
print(len(data), data)

url = "https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com"

request = requests.post(url=URL, data=data, verify=False)
```