# How to prevent python requests from decoding my URL

Tags: python, encoding, python-requests

Hello I want to make a get request and have a URL that contains

```
url = "http://example.com/tags/feature%252Fexample/site/"
```

however if I do a get it changes the URL to a slash and yields an error.

```
requests.get(url)
equests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url:
http://example.com/tags/feature/example/site/
```

Is there a way to keep the url how it is without the `/` ?
I found this question but it is the other way around..
[How to prevent python requests from percent encoding my URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23496750/how-to-prevent-python-requests-from-percent-encoding-my-urls) and was not able to find an option in the documentation.

Thank you.

Comment: Just to be sure. You mean `feature%2Fexample` without the extra `25`, right?

Comment: I tested on my web server, and `requests` is doing the correct request to the server. It just display the "unescaped" URL. I think you are double escape (so the %25).

Comment: The string should stay exactly as given with `feature%252Fexample`

Comment: I tried also that with my webserver, and `requests` will request the right url (so still with %252F in the URL). On Python3. What `requests` print (the "URL") is not what it was really requested.