# Python Requests form-encodes parameters but not URLs

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working with Microsoft Graph API via Python 3 and Requests. The following code works:

```
r = graph_session.get(graph_endpoint + '''/groups?$filter=groupTypes/any(c:c+eq+'Unified')''')
print(r.url)

>>> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=groupTypes/any(c:c+eq+'Unified')
```

However, this does not work:

```
parameters = {'$filter': '''groupTypes/any(c:c+eq+'Unified')'''}
r = graph_session.get(graph_endpoint + '/groups', params=parameters)
print(r.url)

>>> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?%24filter=groupTypes%2Fany%28c%3Ac%2Beq%2B%27Unified%27%29
```

Why does the latter method, which seems to be cleaner, produce a 400 error (Bad request)? It seems like an encoding problem.

Comment: Is it the position of ending quote of `Unified`? `parameters = {'$filter': '''groupTypes/any(c:c+eq+'Unified')'''}`

Comment: @Kamal I don't think so. It should end up as `$filter=groupTypes/any(c:c+eq+'Unified')`

Comment: Yes, you have used that in your working case, but in not-working case, you have done `...'Unified)''''`, which is ending as `...%27Unified%29%27`. But you want it as `...%27Unified%27%29`

Comment: @Kamal Oops, that was just a typo. (I tried again just to be sure; it doesn't work.) I edited the post; thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems like an encoding problem.

Indeed it is, in that case filter expression is getting encoded (which is [by design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)) and Microsoft Graph returns the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid filter clause",
        //...
    }
}
```

The encoding could be prevented if `params` argument is passed as a `string`:

```
parameters = {'$filter': '''groupTypes/any(c:c+eq+'Unified')'''}
parameters_str = "&".join("%s=%s" % (k, v) for k, v in parameters.items())
r = graph_session.get(graph_endpoint + '/groups', params=parameters_str, headers=headers)
```

Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23496750/how-to-prevent-python-requests-from-percent-encoding-my-urls) for another options.

Comment: Thank you! Although less flexible, `parameters = '''$filter:groupTypes/any(c:c+eq+'Unified')'''` also works. Additionally, the [docs](https://2.python-requests.org//en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) mention that passing a string will avoid form-encoding. I didn't know the magic words "form-encoded" and "url encoding."