# Python Requests library undesirable GET request colon escape

Tags: python, get, python-requests

I have a RESTful API I'm requesting from with query string parameters of date_start and date_end. The API documentation states the request should have the date time in a sort of ISO string, like this: 2019-06-15T00:22:55. Setting a date range would look like this:

```
https://path/to/api?start_date=2019-06-15T00:22:55&end_date=2019-08-05T19:55:33
```

Python requests, though, mangles it by wanting to escape the colons (`:`), replacing them with `%3A`, resulting in

```
https://path/to/api?start_date=2019-06-15T00%3A22%3A55&end_date=2019-08-05T19%3A55%3A33
```

Which, unfortunately, the API doesn't regard as a soluble parameter.

When I run the URL from Postman, that formatting doesn't get mangled. However, attempting to connect my app to the API using the typically amazing Requests library, it does the string escape conversion. I'm passing the parameter in a `payload`-style key-value pair, advised by the requests docs, as follows:

```
info_id = 'abcXYZ1234'
url = 'path/to/sandbox'
start = '2019-06-15T00:00:00'
end = '2019-07-15T00:00:00'
payload = {'info_id': info_id, 'start_date': start, 'end_date': end}
r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
info = r.json()
```

How can I prevent requests from escaping colons?

Comment: did you try to use this value directly in url - `requests.get('https://path/to/api?start_date=2019-06-15T00:22:55&end_date=2019-08-05T19:55:33)` ?

Comment: Good question - no, I use it in a param key-value pair. I'll update.

Comment: should also works when you assign as string or bytes to params - as in @Saritus answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent python requests from percent encoding my URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23496750/how-to-prevent-python-requests-from-percent-encoding-my-urls)

Answer (score 4):

You can prevent an encoding of the url by using the `params` parameter of `requests.get`

```
url = 'https://path/to/api'
r = requests.get(url, params='start_date=2019-06-15T00:22:55&end_date=2019-08-05T19:55:33')
```

Converting from the typical payload dictionary structure is quite easy (code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23497912/10833207)

```
payload = {
  'start_date': '2019-06-15T00:22:55',
  'end_date': '2019-08-05T19:55:33'
}

payload_str = "&".join("%s=%s" % (k,v) for k,v in payload.items())

r = requests.get(url, params=payload_str)
```