# Prevent python `requests` from encoding certain characters like symbol bracket in URL

Tags: python, python-requests, urlencode

I need to send a request with query string containing square brackets: `[`, And it should not be encoded as `%5b`.

As the answer in this question [<How to prevent python requests from percent encoding my URLs?>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23497903/11887333) says,
I have tried putting the query string in the URL instead of passing `params` argument to `get()`, but `requests` still decides to encode the `[` character anyway.

Wireshark:

1. Sent with python `requests`:

```py
url = "http://localhost:2017/api/httpLatency?whiches=[%7B%22id%22:26,%22_type%22:%22subscriptionServer%22,%22sub%22:1%7D]"
r = requests.get(url)
```

[image]

2. Another packet containing an unencoded `[` in URL:

[image]

I also tried the solution in this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/1454#issuecomment-20832874) of `request`, which is to prepare the Request object and send it yourself. It doesn't work either.

After doing some testing, I found out that some characters, like `( , : +`, won't be URL-encoded if passed directly as part of URL, but characters like `{ [` will be URL-encoded anyway no matter passed as URL or as `params` arguments.

I wonder if this is a deliberate design of `requests`? If it is, why should `requests` force characters like `[ {` to be encoded, is it due to the safety issue?

And if it is not, is there a workaround for this problem? After hours of searching, I still couldn't find a way to make a request with an un-encoded `[` character in the URL. Using `urllib` would be way too complex for me.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: According to RFC 1738, square brackets are considered to be "unsafe". I quote from the RFC "All unsafe characters must always be encoded within a URL". Therefore, *requests* appears to be fully compliant in this respect

Comment: @DarkKnight Thanks for the info, I'll read the RFC document you mentioned. The link is [URL Character Encoding Issues](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738#section-2.2), just for convenience.

Comment: See [here](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced.html) under PreparedRequests.

Comment: @CypherX Thanks for the link, but I don't think this part  [PreparedRequests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#prepared-requests) is really helping.