# python-requests - prevent URL encoding

Tags: python-requests, urllib3

I find myself attempting to interact with a legacy device with a wonky back-end server that expects many query strings to include curly braces. ex: `http://example.com/thing/page?{item1}{item2}{item3}`

Similar to many issues and posts I've found, the default behavior for requests and urllib3 to encode the URL is causing issues.

Suggestions to [override the _encode_invalid_chars function](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6115#issuecomment-1172198984) doesn't seem to work.

The suggestions to use python-requests prepared requests also don't seem to work.

https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#prepared-requests

I attempted to utilize prepared requests as suggested in past github issues and posts on SO.

Thank you!

- April 2022 - https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6115
- October 2021 - https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/5964
- July 2014 - https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2154
- May 2014 - [How to prevent python requests from percent encoding my URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23496750/how-to-prevent-python-requests-from-percent-encoding-my-urls)
- July 2013 - https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/1454
- January 2012 - https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/369

**Update:** Edited my code block to a working example

**Update2:** Edited my code block to remove the import alias

**Update3:** Update my code block with both working methods

```
    import requests
    import urllib3.util.url

    def hook_invalid_chars(component, allowed_chars):
        # handle url encode here, or do nothing
        return component


    # Method1:
    # Warning: this is a hack to override
    # urllib3.util.url._encode_invalid_chars = hook_invalid_chars

    # Method2 (requires urllib3 around 2.0.7):
    # Warning: this is a hack to make urllib3 allow otherwise invalid characters
    urllib3.util.url._QUERY_CHARS.add('{')
    urllib3.util.url._QUERY_CHARS.add('}')

    url_base = 'http://127.0.0.1:5470/thing/page'
    url_query = '{item1}{item2}{item3}'

    with requests.Session() as sess:    
        # Note: need to use both the hack above and a prepared request
        req = requests.Request(method='GET', url=url_base)
        prep = req.prepare()
        prep.url += f'?{url_query}'
        
        resp = sess.send(prep)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I traced it with pdb. The code responsible for reencoding the URL is in urllib3. It happens inside the HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen() method.

https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/11f5f5e19bfaab9cdfa2ce9223e62b8f05dd2a99/src/urllib3/connectionpool.py#L723-L727

```py
        # Ensure that the URL we're connecting to is properly encoded
        if url.startswith("/"):
            url = to_str(_encode_target(url))
        else:
            url = to_str(parsed_url.url)
```

As far as I can tell, it runs unconditionally. There is no way anything you do in `requests` can override it.

The [urllib3.HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen docs](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.3/reference/urllib3.connectionpool.html#urllib3.HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen) say: "This is the lowest level call for making a request, so you’ll need to specify all the raw details." So there is no even lower level that could override it.

Probably relevant issues:

- https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6385
- https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6392
- https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/3135
- https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/3062 (closed)

If you don't care about maintainability and just want it to work, you could reach into internal urllib3 implementation details and force it to do your bidding.

```py
# HUGE HACK!
import urllib3.util.url
urllib3.util.url._QUERY_CHARS.add('{')
urllib3.util.url._QUERY_CHARS.add('}')
```

Warning! This is obviously a huge hack! Future upgrades of urllib3 might randomly break it. And it is a global change -- it affects the encoding of all requests made by the current Python process.

Another thing to try might be to use `urllib` and `http.client` from the Python standard library. They are generally much harder to use, but perhaps by coincidence they might not reencode the URL.

*Edited to add:* You mentioned overriding the _encode_invalid_chars function. In my testing, both overriding _QUERY_CHARS and overriding _encode_invalid_chars worked (and both have the same disadvantages). Are you sure you're testing it correctly? I used `base_url = "http://localhost:5470/foo"` and ran `nc -l 5470` (netcat) in another terminal, like shown in your link. Your print() might not show the real URL that was requested, there could be another encoding step.

Comment: Thank you for the response Tomi.

In my later tests I was not performing both the manual request as well as overriding _encode_invalid_chars -- doing both **does work**. I was hopeful the "prepared requests" would be a working solution.

Overriding things is definitely hacky and I'd prefer it not be necessary.

Comment: Right, I see, first `requests` encodes it (which can be avoided with a prepared request) and second `urllib3` encodes it again (which cannot be avoided, except using a huge hack to either _QUERY_CHARS or _encode_invalid_chars).

Comment: Out of curiosity I tried your _QUERY_CHARS hack/workaround, but didn't have success.

Comment: My attempts at the _QUERY_CHARS override do not work. (When I put my code block below it isn't formatted as such.)

Tomi, could you share what you have as a full working example of the _QUERY_CHARS "hack" method?

Comment: Sure, here is my code and all library versions and terminal commands I typed: https://pastebin.com/e5MYnXBN Ideas: Are you absolutely sure it's not a problem with your testing setup? Can you see real raw sent bytes, for example with my `nc -l` trick, or with `tcpdump`?

Comment: :facepalm: I mistakenly wasn't using a virtual environment (easy enough fix). This caused me to be using somewhat older versions of requests and urllib3. For curiosity I played around with the versions of requests and urllib3. Once I pulled urllib3 2.0.7 into virtual environment via pip, I was able to get the _QUERY_CHARS method to work. Huge thanks for the pastebin example Tomi!

Comment: I marked the **query chars** method as the answer since I feel it is the lesser evil of the two methods to override code within `urllib3`. The script I plan to write will interact with dozens of the same device model a few times and then I (probably) won't use the script again. Certainly the basic urllib from the standard library allows the most flexibility with some usability trade-offs ... including the time invested to manually manage cookies and so forth that `requests` does for us.

Answer (score 0):

The standard library's basic [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) module allows sending requests with a malformed URL, and does not reencode it.

```py
import urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen('http://localhost:5470/thing/page?{item1}{item2}{item3}') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Running `nc -l 5470` shows that the Python code sent these bytes:

```
GET /thing/page?{item1}{item2}{item3} HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: localhost:5470
User-Agent: Python-urllib/3.10
Connection: close
```

You can also do POST requests:

```py
req = urllib.request.Request(
    url='http://localhost:5470/thing/page?{item1}{item2}{item3}',
    data=b'foo=bar&foo2=bar2')
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as f:
    print(f.read())
```

This is good enough for basic GET or POST requests! But compared to the higher level `requests` and `urllib3` libraries, you won't (automatically) get:

- Keep-Alive, connection reuse and pooling
- file uploads, multipart encoding, chunked requests
- response character encoding detection
- easy cookie handling
- easy Basic HTTP Authentication
- request timeouts
- retry on failure
- HTTP proxy support
- [etc.](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#beloved-features), [etc.](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#urllib3)

Comment: Yes, the tradeoffs.

I'd rather not give up all the benefits of requests and urllib3.

It is a shame I am working with this wonky device I need to interface with.

Comment: Yeah... Personally, I think I would still choose this route. Out of curiosity, is there a *specific* feature of requests or urllib3 you're missing, or just a general worry you will need something later?

Comment: Heh, what I'm trying to pull together was supposed to be quick script, but it is turning not to be so (thanks to a vendor's design). I'll have to handle cookies manually. Hopefully not much more, but it has proven to be a Pandora's box. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: It's pretty ugly, but you could try [http.cookiejar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html#examples). BTW "like, comment and subscribe", errrr cough cough I mean upvote and accept. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Im currently working on a fuzzing tool and need an option to inject unencoded payloads into the URL/Headers. I replace my fuzzing point but you can insert any character that you want to be unencoded e.g. replace("%7B", "{")

```
import urllib3
import requests

def custom_make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout=urllib3.connectionpool._Default, chunked=False, **httplib_request_kw):
    url = url.replace("FUZZ", "TEST!/&%$=)()")
    new_headers = {}
    for header, value in httplib_request_kw['headers'].items():
        new_header = header.replace("FUZZ", "TEST!/&%$=)()")
        new_value = value.replace("FUZZ", "TEST!/&%§")
        new_headers[new_header] = new_value
    httplib_request_kw['headers'] = new_headers
    return self._original_make_request(conn, method, url, timeout=timeout, chunked=chunked, **httplib_request_kw)

# Create a reference to the original _make_request method
urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPConnectionPool._original_make_request = urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPConnectionPool._make_request
# Replace the _make_request method with the custom_make_request function
urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPConnectionPool._make_request = custom_make_request

response = requests.get('http://<YOUR_TEST_SERVER>/FUZZ')
```

Comment: Nice.

With the basic manual test from above using netcat this seems to be another option for overcoming URL encoding.

Thank you.